# ServerSide error JSON por Ñ y acentos

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

Llevo un par de días peleándome con las Ñ y las tildes.

Uso DataTable mediante ServerSide, para mostrar la información de una tabla de empresas. El problema es que me da un error, cuando encuentra caracteres Ñ o acentos. En la base de datos me lo guarda correctamente. No se que hacer y me estoy volviendo bastante loco jaja

Os proporciono como hago las llamadas y al función para sacar y mostrar la información.

**EDITO**

Este es el error que me genera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> *JS → Llamada mediante AJAX*

```
   /* Llamada al controlador para sacar las empresas */
    $('#server-side-datatable').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        'ordering': true,
        'orderCellsTop': true,
        "ajax": `${SERVERU}controlador/empresa/controlador_mostrar_empresa.php`,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, "ALL"]
        ],
        "columns": [{
            "data": "empre_nombre_soporte"
        },
        {
            "data": "empre_nombre_administracion"
        },
        {
            "data": "empre_antiguedad"
        },
        {
            "data": "empre_estado"
        },
        {
            "data": "empre_observaciones"
        },
        {
            "data": "actions"
        }
        ],
    });
```

> *PHP*

> 1- Controlador que llama a la función

```
<?php

require '../../modelo/empresa..modelo_empresa.php';

$mod_empre = new Modelo_Empresa();
$data = $mod_empre->MostrarEmpresasTabla();

echo $data;

?>
```

> 2- Funcion para mostrar las empresas

```
 /* Funcion para mostrar las empresas en una tabla  */
    function MostrarEmpresasTabla()
    {
        $dbDetails = conexion::__constructArray(); //Parametros de la base
        $table = 'crm_empresa';
        $primaryKey = 'empre_id';
        $btnDetails = '';
        $columns = array(
            array(
                'db' => 'empre_id',
                'dt' => 'DT_RowId',
                'formatter' => function ($d, $row) {
                    return $d;
                }
            ),
            array('db' => 'empre_nombre_soporte', 'dt' => 'empre_nombre_soporte'),
            array('db' => 'empre_nombre_administracion', 'dt' => 'empre_nombre_administracion'),
            array(
                'db' => 'empre_antiguedad',
                'dt' => 'empre_antiguedad',
                'formatter' => function ($d, $row) {
                    return date("d-m-Y", strtotime($d));
                }
            ),
            array('db' => 'empre_estado', 'dt' => 'empre_estado'),
            array('db' => 'empre_observaciones', 'dt' => 'empre_observaciones'),
            array(
                'db' => 'actions',
                'dt' => 'actions',
                'formatter' => function () {
                    $btnDetails = BUTTON_VIEW;
                    $btnDetails = $btnDetails . BUTTON_DELETE;
                    return $btnDetails;
                }
            )
        );
        return json_encode(SSP::simple($_GET, $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

> 3- Llamada a la clase ssp.class que es la librería para hacer llamadas, mediante ServerSide.

```
/**
     * Perform the SQL queries needed for an server-side processing requested,
     * utilising the helper functions of this class, limit(), order() and
     * filter() among others. The returned array is ready to be encoded as JSON
     * in response to an SSP request, or can be modified if needed before
     * sending back to the client.
     *
     *  @param  array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     *  @param  array|PDO $conn PDO connection resource or connection parameters array
     *  @param  string $table SQL table to query
     *  @param  string $primaryKey Primary key of the table
     *  @param  array $columns Column information array
     *  @return array          Server-side processing response array
     */
    static function simple ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
             FROM `$table`
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`
             $where"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
             FROM   `$table`"
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];

        /*
         * Output
         */
        return array(
            "draw"            => isset ( $request['draw'] ) ?
                intval( $request['draw'] ) :
                0,
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Te da error: ¿te muestra un mensaje en concreto o muestra los datos incorrectamente? Pulsa en [edit] y especifícalo en la pregunta. Además, no olvides configurar el formato de codificación de caracteres (_character encoding_).

Comment: @padaleiana Editado. Gracias por contestar :) .Me muestra un error de datos erróneos al devolver el JSON. Se que es por las ñ y las tildes, porque si quito estos caracteres, me funciona correctamente y me muestra la información.

Comment: Pon el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes. Por cierto, a esto iba con que [no olvides configurar el charset](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/47358/ssp-class-php-especial-characters-problem-solution) (error mío, _encoding_ no es lo mismo que _charset_) :)

Comment: Te quiero @padaleiana jajajaja. Lo tengo, era eso. En mi clase ModeloConexion , tengo forzado el UTF8, pero no lo había puesto para la función que pasa los parámetros a la clase que hace la conexion. Realizo respuesta ahora mismo. Muchiiiiiisimas gracias y que tengas un Feliz Año !! :D

Comment: ¡Genial! Luego de escribir tu respuesta, no olvides [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 3):

De primeras gracias a @padaleiana.

Básicamente, mi solución es que tenéis que pasar el tipo de CHARSET a la funcion que hace la conexion en la clase ssp.class.php.

Tenéis que añadir  el charset y luego en tu función que pasas el array de lo detalles de conexion, agregas el tipo de charset.

SSP.CLASS.php

```
static function sql_connect ( $sql_details )
    {
        try {
            $db = @new PDO(
                "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']};charset={$sql_details['charset']}",
                $sql_details['user'],
                $sql_details['pass'],
                array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
            );
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            self::fatal(
                "An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
                "The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
            );
        }

        return $db;
    }
```

modelo_conexion.php (asi lo que he llamado yo)

```
public static function __constructArray()
    {
        $dbDetails = array (
            'host' => SERVER_HOST,
            'user' => SERVER_USER,
            'pass' => SERVER_PASS,
            'charset' => CHARSET, //Aqui pasamos el CHARSET UTF8
            'db' => SERVER_BD
        );
        return $dbDetails;
    }
```